# AWS Athena to write and create tagged objects as s3 output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I want to run an Athena query. Athena always writes the results to s3. I want all these resulting files to have tags. For example, the tags of the workgroup the query run in.

In that example the results of

```
client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString='some query',
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 's3://path/to/query/bucket/'
    },
    WorkGroup='my_wg'
)
```

Would be written to `s3://path/to/query/bucket/` with the tags of workgroup `my_wg`. Is it possible, if so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

S3 events on objects written by Athena don't provide any information that may be useful for tagging through a Lambda function. We can rule that a solution for now.

The other way without writing any code is to set a different path prefix for the output location associated for your different workgroups.

If you want to proceed with manually tagging, `QueryExecutionId` is returned in the result.

You can retrieve the object location where the query results are written to and tag them.

```py
import time
import boto3
from urllib.parse import urlparse


workgroup = "my_wg"
workgroup_tag = {"Key": "workgroup", "Value": workgroup}

athena_client = boto3.client("athena", region_name="us-east-1")
response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString="some query",
    ResultConfiguration={
        "OutputLocation": "s3://path/to/query/bucket/"
    },
    WorkGroup=workgroup
)
query_execution_id = response['QueryExecutionId']

state = None
output_location = None

while True:
    response = athena_client.get_query_execution(
        QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id
    )
    query_execution = response["QueryExecution"]
    state = query_execution["Status"]["State"]
    if state in ["QUEUED", "RUNNING"]:
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        if state == "SUCCEEDED":
            output_location = query_execution["ResultConfiguration"]["OutputLocation"]
        break

# Now proceed to tagging
s3_client = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
if output_location:
    parse_result = urlparse(output_location)
    bucket = parse_result.netloc
    key = parse_result.path.lstrip('/')
    
    # Add tag to existing tags on the object.
    response = s3.get_object_tagging(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    tag_set = response["TagSet"]
    tag_set.append(workgroup_tag)
    tagging = {"TagSet": tag_set}

    response = s3.put_object_tagging(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Tagging=tagging)
```

> As a result of this much ado about tagging query results.
> I recommend configuring different path prefix for the output location associated for your different workgroups. That way you don't have to manually tag them.